# ListView in Kivy

Tags: android, kivy

I am trying to create a ListView widget in Kivy, but cannot; am using Python 3.10 and Kivy 2.0. Later I changed it to RecycleView. Window is opening but items in the item_strings property of RecycleView are not getting displayed.

```
    AddLocationForm:

    <AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:

    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:

        TextInput:

        Button:
            text: 'Search'
        
        Button:
            text: 'Current Location'

    RecycleView:

        item_strings: ["Kolkata", 'New Delhi']
```

My main.py is as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App

class WeatherApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = WeatherApp()
    app.run()
```

Can you help me out.

Comment: I am not aware of any `item_strings` property of `RecycleView`. Check the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html).

Comment: So what should I write in place of item_strings so that the items get displayed.

Comment: Use `data`, but read the documentation, because it is not a list of strings.